# Correcting CGI Website Error

Tags: sql-server

Please the website to my organization is currently showing this web address upon log in:

http://www.networkforreforms.org/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi

Hence, we cannot browse the website or access the webmaster.

Kindly advise us on how to re-write the sub-domain or simply rectify this prolonged problem.

Thank you very much for your possible contribution.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see you use cPanel / WHM. Please look up the following log to find possible errors:

```
tail -f /usr/local/apache/logs/error_log
```

Have you made any changes to your web site's configuration recently?

If you messed up with the httpd.conf, the following script might help:

```
/scripts/rebuildhttpdconf
```